# Get span and h3 on same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

This should be so simple, yet it's eluding me. I just want my `span` and my `h3` to appear on the same line, one next to the other, but they're appearing on different lines. Could someone send some help my way?

```css
header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

header .glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the browser applies default styles to the `h3` element. A quick work around would be adding a `display: inline;` style to the `h3`.

```css
header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

header .glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 5px;
}

h3 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `display: flex` is overriden by bootstrap `display: block` style. Use `important` or more specific selector to override this. Also add `align-items: baseline` to put flex-items on font's baseline.

Demo:

```css
header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100% !important;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: baseline;
}

header .glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</header>
```

By the way `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` answers work due to default `vertical-align: baseline` property for inline elements.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was wondering why flex wasn't doing anything. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the elements inside to `display: inline-block;`

```css
header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

header .glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 5px;
}

header > span,
header > h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</header>
```

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov , do you think adding `inline` to `h3` is the better practice? Do you think it's poor practice to do `inline-block` to both elements?

Comment: Adding `inline` to `h3` is not so flexible because you can't add `margin`s, `width`, `height`, `padding`s and so on. But to be honest I prefer flexbox because it blockifies all its children flex items and have a lot of layout options comparing to `inline-block`s. Also consider removing `display: flex` from you code since you are not planning to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

`h3` is an block element by default. `span` is inline.

Your `h3` should have `display: inline`, our `inline-block`.

https://jsfiddle.net/h81pkpne/1/

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` should work looks like `<header>` is being overiden by normalize.css to `display: block` so applied class `.header` and removed margin from h3.

other answers provided using inline (or a float) would also work

```css
.header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .glyphicon {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 2px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="header">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</header>
```